# PHP запрос MS SQL проблемы кодировки

Tags: php, sql-server

Всем доброго времени суток! Вы моя последняя надежда. Есть php сервер, php v 5.6.32.
Есть БД MSSQL(Microsoft SQL Server).
Из php необходимо отправлять insert/select запросы в базу. Для подключения использую mssql_connect, mssql_query(php). Кодировка php скрипта utf-8.

Всё бы хорошо если бы русский текст не возвращался в виде "????????". Также select-запросы в которых в качестве условия используются русские слова ничего не возвращают.

Функция mb_detect_encoding показала что возвращается ASCII. Попытки конвертации iconv и mb_convert_encoding ни к чему не привели, возвращает по прежнему "????????". Я слышал что подобная проблема возникает, но на просторах интернета не нашёл решения которое подходило бы или работало бы в моём случае.
Пожалуйста, подскажите пожалуйста что можно сделать, кто с этим сталкивался и как решали данную проблему, я уже в отчаянии.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: самому соединению с БД установите кодировку

Comment: Может покажусь тупым =) но каким образом? Функция mssql_connect(http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mssql-connect.php) не даёт такой возможности.

Comment: ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');

Comment: ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8'); пробовал, оно себя как то странно ведёт, если ставить до подключения то он не может подключиться, если после, то толку понятно дело нет.

Comment: Всё, заработало. Не понятно правда почему до того как Вы написали про ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8'); оно не работало, а после того заработало. Ох уж то программирование! Всем спасибо большое!

Comment: я просто пару раз в бубен у себя тут ударил